# How to not use a user input if it's invalid?

Tags: java

My program asks a user for test scores and displays the min/max, # of tests, and the average. However, if the score isn't between 0 and 10 I don't want that number used in my calculations. How would I go about doing that in my do/while loop? I've tried entering 
System.exit(0); after line  if (num <= 0 || num >10)
            System.out.println("Score must be between 10 and 0");
        but it breaks my program.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class QuizScoreStatistics {
public static void main (String args[]) {
      float max=0;
    float min=99;
    float avg=0;
    float count=0;
    float sum=0;
    float num;
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input test scores with values between 0-10.\nEnter 99 to finish.");
    num=scan.nextInt();
    float temp=num;

    do
    {
        if(num==99) 
            System.exit(0);

        if (num <= 0 || num >10)
        System.out.println("Score must be between 10 and 0");



        if(num>=0 && num<=100)
        {
            count++;
            sum+=num;
            if(num>max ) 
                max=num;
            if(num<min)
                min=num;
        }
    } while((num=scan.nextInt())!=99);

   // System.out.println("Test Statistics:");
    System.out.println("Number of tests: "+count);
    System.out.println("Lowest: "+min);
    System.out.println("Highest: "+max);;
    System.out.printf("Average: " + sum/count);
}
```

}

Comment: After you fix your loop read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Answer (score 3):

You can try continuing the rest of the do-while loop.

```
if (num <= 0 || num >10){
        System.out.println("Score must be between 10 and 0");
        continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a continue

```
if(num <= 0 || num > 10){
    System.out.println("wrong asnwer");
    num = scan.nextInt();
    continue;
}
```

continue will skip to the next iteration of the loop.
So you start the loop over.

Comment: Oh yea, in that case you can just do continue. Didn't see.